# Sourcemaps don't work with coffeescript and webpack in gulp

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, webpack, source-maps

I am writing an application in coffeescript and using gulp to build the frontend. My current dev build looks like this

```
gulp.task 'coffee', ->
    gulp.src('./coffee/*.coffee')
        .pipe do plumber
        .pipe sourcemaps.init()
        .pipe coffee bare: true
        .pipe sourcemaps.write()
        .pipe gulp.dest './pre-js/'

gulp.task 'webpack', ['coffee'], ->
    return gulp.src('pre-js/main.js')
        .pipe webpack require './webpack.config.js'
        .pipe gulp.dest 'dist/js/'
```

currently in `coffee` directory I only have two files `main.coffee` and `styles.coffee`, my webpack.config looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./pre-js/main.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "main.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
    ]
  },
  target: "web"
};
```

Before I added webpack my sourcemaps worked and I could easily track everything from the console. Once I added webpack all console.log's are pointing at `styles.coffee`. I am noting that no minification is happening at this point.

How can I fix my build process to continue writing a modular application while being able to use the goodness of the sourcemaps?

Comment: missing `devtool: "source-map"` in webpack config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing `devtool: "source-map"` in webpack config file